# Example where $m(G) - m(A) \leq m(G \setminus A)$ does not hold

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've read that given a set $A$ with finite outer measure, where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists an open set $G$ s.t. $A \subseteq G$ and $m(G) - m(A) < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

However, it is not always the case that we have $m(G) - m(A) \leq m(G \setminus A)$. What example is there where this fails?

Comment: do you mean $G\setminus A$? if so, it always is the case, by additivity of measure. if $m$ refers to outer measure, then $A$ needs to be non-measurabl

Comment: Do you mean $G \setminus A$? Otherwise I don’t see what could be $G/A$ in this context.

Comment: There are many errors in your statements. You forgot to say that $A$ is measurable and you forgot the condition $A \subset G$. Even with these condition the first sentence is wrong. Ex. If $ A=\mathbb R^{n}$ then $G=A$ amd $m(G)-m(A)$ is not defined.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question. $A$ is supposed to have finite outer measure and it shoulf be $G \setminus A$ and not $G / A$